# Creating a web app that can work offline, store data and then sync it to remote MySQL when online?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I am looking to create a web app written in PHP / MySQL.  It will be used to collect data on houses by staff walking around a neighbourhood.  There may be places where they have little to no cell signal, so I need a way to allow them to still view the web app when offline, as well as store the data they are submitting, to be inserted to the MySQL database once their phone has a signal / wi fi.

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: `Is something like this even possible?`  It certainly is.  I use my own offline syncing / db.  But for a kick start into offline databases & syncing.  You could have a look at PouchDB / CouchDB combo..

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is possible. Although there are many different alternatives, ["Progressive Web Apps" (PWA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_app) is one of the trending topic of today. They provide mobile app experience with responsive and mobile site. They also provide standalone mode.

You can use [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache), [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)... to store data.

You need [Service Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) to sync your application with database or to manage your application when the user is offline.

Google's documentation about [PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/)s may be a good point to start. Also you can dive into [offline storage for pwa](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa) docs of Google.

This is a good blog to describe the features of [PWA](https://dockyard.com/blog/2017/09/14/pwas-instead-of-mobile-apps-mobile-sites-and-responsive-design)s.

**UPDATE AT 2018 APRIL:**

With IOS 11.3, Safari 11.1 was released with service worker support. Reference: [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_11_1.html)

Thanks [@ChrisLove](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82708/chris-love) for [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46532965/creating-a-web-app-that-can-work-offline-store-data-and-then-sync-it-to-remote/46533370?noredirect=1#comment86599329_46533370)

Comment: Thanks very much for this info.  It will be a great starting point for me.

Comment: After doing some reading, am I correct that iOS does not support PWAs?  Looks like even if you are using Chrome on iOS, it doesn't allow you to use things like service workers.

Comment: PWA's is just a starting point. [In another blog of Dockyard](https://dockyard.com/blog/2017/07/13/safari-ios-and-progressive-web-apps), you can see the status of ios. Instead of Service Worker you may need to build your own mechanism. Such as using [navigator.online](https://caniuse.com/#search=navigator.online) event + ajax requests to be sync with server side.

Comment: By the way, currently mobile app development for ios has a requirement of building the code in mac os. Progressive web apps are breaking this requirement. I don't believe that Apple like the PWA idea :)

Comment: At this point we have almost 100% platform support for Progressive web apps. Apple recently shipped a Safari update that included initial service worker support https://love2dev.com/blog/apple-shipps-service-workers/. Microsoft turned service workers on by default last Fall in the Insiders Edition which is going to production for general use right now.
We have been able to do offline for years, service workers make it much better. 
To persist data you can use IndexedDB, I recommend a library like localForage to help.
You may also want to investigate SW background sync for your scenario.